# ¿Cómo usar el operador << de la clase padre desde una clase hija?

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Tengo dos clases, una padre y otra hija, ambas tienen definida su propia sobrecarga del operador << con la cual poder mostrar sus respectivos datos, pero al momento de definir el operador << en la clase hija no consigo mostrar los datos que hereda de su padre, solo aparecen los atributos definidos en la clase hija.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

/*==== Clase Padre ====*/

struct Animal{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Animal &ob){
        return os <<"Especie: "<<ob.especie<<'\n'
                  <<"Raza   : "<<ob.raza;
    }
    string especie;
    string raza;
    Animal(string especie_, string raza_) : especie{especie_}, raza{raza_}{}
};

/*==== Clase Hija ====*/

struct Mascota : public Animal{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Mascota &ob){
        return os <<"Nombre: "<<ob.nombre<<'\n'
                  <<"Edad  : "<<ob.edad;
    }
    string nombre;
    int edad;
    Mascota(string nombre_, int edad_, string especie_, string raza_) : Animal(especie_,raza_), nombre{nombre_}, edad{edad_}{}
};

int main(){
    Mascota mascota("toto",3,"gato","bengali");

    cout<<mascota<<"\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Nombre: toto
Edad  : 3
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
Nombre : toto
Edad   : 3
Especie: gato
Raza   : bengali
```

Ya sé que de todas formas es posible acceder a los atributos de la clase padre porque se están heredando, pero como este ya tiene definida la sobrecarga del operador << ¿cómo puedo hacer uso de él desde la clase hija?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás confundido. Si bien las funciones están dentro de los structs, no son métodos, son simplemente funciones que podrías haber declarado en otra parte.

La palabra clave `friend` les permite ver los miembros privados del struct. Si la funciones fueran métodos no necesitarías usarla. Por lo tanto no se hereda.

Otra razón que refuerza esta situación es el hecho de que la sobrecarga de operadores no son más que funciones. Por lo que si fueran métodos podrías llamarlos así:

```
mascota.operator<<(cout, mascota);
```

O así:

```
Mascota::operator<<(cout, mascota);
```

Pero solo puedes así:

```
operator<<(cout, mascota);
```

---

En fin, para llamar a la otra función te ves forzado a convertir la `Mascota` en una referencia de tipo `Animal`. Así:

```
return os << (const Animal&)ob
          << "\nNombre: " << ob.nombre
          << "\nEdad  : " << ob.edad;
```

---

Considera el siguiente escenario:

```
struct Animal {
    ...

public:
    void imprimir(std::ostream& os) {
        os << "\nEspecie: " << especie
           << "\nRaza   : " << raza;
    }
};

/*==== Clase Hija ====*/

struct Mascota : public Animal {
    ...

public:
    void imprimir(std::ostream& os) {
        Animal::imprimir(os);
        os << "\nNombre: " << nombre
           << "\nEdad  : " << edad;
    }
};
```

Ambas funciones `imprimir` claramente son métodos. Aquí sí puedes llamar a la función del padre escribiendo si nombre, dos puntos y el nombre de la función a llamar.

Comment: Gracias por responder, he probado las dos formas y ambas funcionan, pero por requerimientos me estaría quedando con la de convertir el objeto mascota porque me da más libertad de elegir el orden en que se muestran los datos, pero no entiendo por qué no utilizaste static_cast o dynamic_cast tengo entendido que son para objetos heredados ¿no?

Comment: @Accimus por comodidad. Los casts de C tienen sus desventajas, pero no es el propósito de la pregunta. Puedes ver lo que dicen en [SO inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/13419694) 
o formular una pregunta al respecto. Sucede que cuando el compilador ese encuentra con un cast de C [intenta realizar conversiones se C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast#Explanation). Puedes comprobarlo [aquí](https://cppinsights.io/s/954f0d55).

Comment: Por cierto, podría simplemente haber dejado que una conversión implícita ocurra: `const Animal& animal = ob; os << animal << ...`. El cast era para no ocupar un nombre adicional.

Comment: Interesante gracias de nuevo!!